# Treemap in d3 v5 doesn't support nodes anymore

Tags: d3.js

Using this example http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/raw/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022/dd9e5ec5489b00e7509378c37bc797309f3c2aa3/ (uses v3) with the latest version of d3 which is v5, I am unable to get a treemap.

The example uses treemap.nodes, but that is no longer a function in v5 and I'm not able to find an alternative way to get the treemap to generate the x/y positions for the nodes using v5.

Here is a section of code that contains the function in question:

```
function layout(d) {
if (d._children) {
  treemap.nodes({_children: d._children});
  d._children.forEach(function(c) {
    c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
    c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
    c.dx *= d.dx;
    c.dy *= d.dy;
    c.parent = d;
    layout(c);
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bring your attention to D3.js's [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy), which serves as a migration guide. It'll probably be very useful when it comes to such situations when you have to migrate from v3 to v5.

Here is the detailed documentation for [d3.treemap](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#treemap).

Looking at the [original code](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#treemap), you will have to make quite a fair bit of changes, and not just the code you have pasted above.

You'll probably should start something like this:

```
const treemap = d3.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(2);

const nodes = treemap(root
    .sum(d => d.value)
    .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value))
    .descendants();
```

As stated over [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#hierarchy):

> You must call node.sum or node.count before invoking a hierarchical
>   layout that requires node.value, such as d3.treemap.

Comment: I will take a look at this and see if I can apply it to the zoomable treemap example.